# Unable to make API call from react native app in local machine

Tags: firebase, react-native, fetch

I'm running my app on android emulator on my mac and trying to hit a service endpoint which is deployed on firebase. I'm getting 500 error saying nothing and when I'm trying to print the error it says `There was a problem sending log messages to your development environment [PrettyFormatPluginError: value.hasOwnProperty is not a function. (In 'value.hasOwnProperty('tag')', 'value.hasOwnProperty' is undefined)]`.

When I try to hit the same endpoint using postman and the same payload, I'm succesfully able to do it.

Following code is written in the app

```
fetch('https://{app_url}.cloudfunctions.net/app/user', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     body: userPayload
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => {
     console.log('User in DB created');
     console.log(result);
})
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: Just guessing userPayload may be null or missing the tag information your backend is expecting and you're probably testing with.

Comment: Hello @Atmas,
I'm passing the same payload from my app and there is no tag information that's also required. But it's of no help.

Comment: Could you paste your user payload?

Comment: What about "app_url"? Are you sure it's pointing to the correct URL?

Comment: The payload:
{
    "dob": "09/09/1996",
    "email": "test1@gmail.com",
    "nameOfTheUser": "ABtest",
    "phoneNumber": "9898989898",
    "userId": "49178"
}

Comment: The app_url at both locations, the app codebase and postman, are the same. No difference between them,

Comment: Is userPayload a string? Otherwise, have you tried using "body: JSON.stringify(userPayload)"?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting Accept: 'application/json', so you should change ".then(response => response.text())" to ".then(response => response.json())". Let me know if it works.

```
fetch('https://{app_url}.cloudfunctions.net/app/user', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     body: userPayload
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
     console.log('User in DB created');
     console.log(result);
})
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Hello,
It didn't help.

Comment: Good idea.. but if he's getting a 500 error it will fall into the .catch immediately and not even hit this line.